# How to import content with a Windows Service to Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

So I'm making this website that needs some external data that I want to be imported automatically, so I don't have to go into the CMS and import a file every day, or multiple times a day. The way I see it I should create the document types that I need and have some sort of API to connect to the Umbraco when i read the data from it's source.

I've looked at the [ContentService](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService) but since I don't have the right ApplicationContext the ContentService throws a NullReferenceException.

Anyone have a sample code or some knowledge on how to go about doing this?

I know the "easy" solotion is to make a hack that imports the data around Umbraco, directly into the DB. But I fell there should be a API for this...

Answer (score 0):

Build your own lightweight API that runs where your back office runs and uses ContentService under the covers to do the actual DB work. Your Windows Service makes use of that ligthweight API. I'm not aware of a REST API baked into Umbraco for external use (that would be cool). [This article](http://www.nibble.be/?p=224) walks through building a lightweight REST service on top of ContentService and takes advantage of Umbraco's easy to use [WebApi](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/) too. His purpose is using it from AngularJS but it's the same approach for accessing from a Windows Service.